# train classifier to detect only eyelashes/nose features dlib and opencv?

Tags: opencv, dlib

## I want to know that how can i train cascade classifier to detect only eyelashes or nose feature points in DLIB and [OPENCV][2]#

1. To be more clear i just want to extract some particular feature points to text file.
2. i tried extracting features but to no avail it gives all 68 points.

[2]: http://opencv.org/#I want to know that how can i train cascade classifier to detect only eyelashes or nose feature points in [A][1] and [B][2]# 
1. To be more clear i just want to extract some particular feature points to text file.
2. i tried extracting features but to no avail it gives all 68 points.

Comment: dlib and opencv has different ways to train classifier (detector). are you trying to detect eyelashes/nose by dlib or opencv?

Comment: i am able to successfully detect it by dlib. what i want is to extract only some feature points instead of all 68.

Comment: i'm writing it in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Dlib python api starting point should be this sample http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html

As you see - it has face detection and shape prediction:

```
dets = detector(img, 1)
...
shape = predictor(img, d)
```

The shape object contain face shape as a list of feature point coordinates - parts. Each part is one point, for example shape.part(30) is a tip of nose. You can see their numbers on sample pictures [from this blog](https://matthewearl.github.io/2015/07/28/switching-eds-with-python/)

[image: Here you can see point numbers]

As I understand, you need simply save this points into file, that can be done like this:

```
with open("sample_file.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(30, 32):
       f.write("{};{}\n".format(i, shape.part(i)))
```

Where 30-32 are part numbers that you want to write to file

Comment: oh man! you nailed it. i have been thinking around for 20 hours and you did it just like that. thanks.

Comment: @Evgeniy how can I trained data for nose, or eyes, or lips only? So that I can reduce the size of model data file.